# Fail in keeping data from $http.get() - AngularJS 1.3.13

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, http, angularjs-ng-repeat

Asking this question after failing to make any other answer I found here work.

I'm trying to make a really simple Client / Server connection.

In my server (Django) I have a view that returns a JSON of objects.
In my client I have an $http.get() that should retrieve that data.

The issue start when I try to hold on to that data.
The data makes it way to client alright, but is gone after the success() function is over.

Any help would be appreciated.

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('photoComments', [])

angular.module('photoComments').controller('PhotoCommentsController', function($http){

    var vm = this;
    vm.activePhoto = {};
    vm.photos = [];
    vm.setActivePhoto = setActivePhoto;

    function setActivePhoto(photo) {
       vm.activePhoto = photo;
    }

    vm.success = function(result) {
        vm.photos = result.data;
    }   

    $http.get("photos/").then(vm.success);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="photoComments" ng-controller="PhotoCommentsController as appCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset class="list-group-item">
                <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="photo in appCtrl.photos">
                    <div>
                        <img ng-src="{{photo.photo_path}}" class="img-responsive" ng-click="setActivePhoto(photo)"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

When debugging with Chrome Developer Tools, and breakpoint the success function, I see that the data arrived and looks ok.

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing `var vm = this;`

Comment: then() takes a function as a callback, you can't pass a statement to it.
$http.get("photos/").then(function(response){});

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand `$scope.success` is a function (it's stored in this variable right above the usage), so I doubt this is the problem.

Comment: ah my bad, didn't notice it.

Comment: Edited to code, after posting old version. I did define var vm = this; and used only vm.* and not $scope

Comment: Is the ng-repeat working? I mean I get that you don't see anything but does it repeat and create the div's in the DOM?

Comment: You need to `return vm.photos` in your success function. Full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice suggests explicit declaration of dependencies to make it work with minification so to clean up, I would do:

```
angular.module('photoComments', [])

angular.module('photoComments').controller('PhotoCommentsController', ['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope){

    $scope.activePhoto = {};
    $scope.photos = [];
    $scope.setActivePhoto = setActivePhoto;

    function setActivePhoto(photo) {
       $scope.activePhoto = photo;
    }

    $scope.success = function(result) {
        $scope.photos = result.data;
    }   

    $http.get("photos/").then($scope.success);
});
```

and

```
<body ng-app="photoComments" ng-controller="PhotoCommentsController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset class="list-group-item">
                <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
                    <div>
                        <img ng-src="{{photo.photo_path}}" class="img-responsive" ng-click="setActivePhoto(photo)"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

You can keep using `vm` but you'd have to parse in `$scope` and define `var vm = $scope` for AngularJS <= 1.1

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have tried out your code, but still it didn't work. I've added a photo from the Chrome Developer tools, maybe it will shed the light on the issue..

Comment: It looks as though this is no longer an AngularJS issue, but a Django one. I'll start checking there, thanks a lot for your help everyone.

Comment: So, The issue was about Django templates and the fact that it is sharing the "{" with AngularJS. the fix was to use Django's {% verbatim %} tag before the {{photo.photo_path}}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `var vm = this;`. So you are adding values to `vm` and using the controller as syntax which means you bind stuff to `this` (or `vm` after `var vm = this`). You are mixing `$scope` and `vm` as well. You need to `return` the `vm.photos` as well to resolve the promise. I would recommend reading this style guide and especially the part about data-services: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#data-services

To fix it:

```
angular.module('photoComments').controller('PhotoCommentsController', function($http){
 var vm = this;
 vm.activePhoto = {};
 vm.photos = [];
 vm.setActivePhoto = setActivePhoto;

 function setActivePhoto(photo) {
     vm.activePhoto = photo;
 }

 vm.success = function(result) {
     vm.photos = result.data;
     return vm.photos;
 }   

 $http.get("photos/").then(vm.success);
});
```